# Find area between $f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2-1,&x<1,\\\ln(x),&x\geq1\end{cases}$ and $x$-axis to the right of the absolute extrema

Tags: calculus, integration, area

> Given $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2-1,&x<1,\\\ln(x),&x\geq1,\end{cases}$$ find the area between $f(x)$ and $x$-axis to the right of the absolute extremum.

---

The $x$-axis is the equation $y=0$. We have the formula of $f$. Also, [I have asked about the absolute extremum of $f$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3285558/525384)  and I have received a proof that $x=0$ is the (unique) absolute minimum of $f$.

With all this, I am not able to understand what "$x$-axis to the right of the absolute extrema" means. Does it mean "The range $x\geq0$"?

Perhaps we can graph all the involved parts:

[image: Area]

and see that we need to find $$\int_0^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.$$ For $x<1$ we have $f(x)\leq0$, and for $x\geq1$ we have $f(x)\geq0$. Hence, the area is $$A=-\int_0^1(x^2-1)\,\mathrm dx+\int_1^\infty\ln(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$ **But $\int_1^\infty\ln(x)\,\mathrm dx$ diverges**, so $A=\infty$, but it does not make sense at all.

Where is my mistake or what do you interpret by "$x$-axis to the right of the absolute extrema"?

Thanks!!

Comment: There is only one absolute extrema point: $\;(0,-1)\;$ , as it can easily been seen from your graph. To the right of this point means $\;x\ge 0\;$ ... **but** I think it is the *enclosed* domain, not all $\;x\ge 0\;$ ... Nevertheless, the intersection of $\;\ln x\;$ and $\;x^2-1\;$ seems to be messier than apparently shown by the above graph...

Comment: @DonAntonio so my thought was right. That means $A=\infty$, right?

Comment: @DonAntonio what do you mean by "*enclosed* domain"? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps not, if the only meant the area  for $\;0\le x\le 1\;$ ... i.e., only the *enclosed* area. Otherwise, yes: the area is infinite as there is a divergent improper integral.

Comment: I have asked to WA and gives $A=5.522502947974294×10^{27954}$ ([link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+0+to+inf+of+piecewise%5B%7B%7Bx%5E2-1,x%3C1%7D,%7Bln(x),x%3E%3D1%7D%7D%5D,x%3E%3D0,y%3D0)), is my input correct?

Comment: For any practical purpose, that number $\;A\;$ is $\;\infty\;$ ...

Comment: Much more interesting would have been to ask for the area **enclosed** between the graphs of the functions $\;f(x)=x^2-1\,,\,\,g(x)=\ln x\;$ ...

Comment: Hm, now I am re-thinking about the statement... It says "$x$-axis", not "$y$-axis", so we would need to move to the right with respect to $y=0$...? That seems strange; moving to the right with respect to an horizontal line seems not possible.

Comment: The word ”extrema” is plural, which (at least for me) added further to the confusion, since there's only one in this case. It should be “extremum”.

Comment: @HansLundmark since we have proven that there is a unique extremum, we can replace "extremum" by "extrema". I think there is no confusion there, but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Well, I'm almost sure they meant the area between that portion of the parabola and the axis to the right of the $\;y\,-$ axis...

Comment: @DonAntonio I am not sure if I understand you correctly. Could you please describe in a graph what do you mean? Thanks!